# Are pseudomonoids weak algebras for a 2-monad?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads

I would like to know if whether or not the pseudomonoids in an arbitrary monoidal 2-category are (equivalent to) the weak algebras for some 2-monad (I am thinking about the free monoidal category 2-monad)?

In case of a positive answer, I also wonder if morphisms of pseudomonoids correspond to morphism of weak algebras.

(Would it be possible to have also pointers to the relevant literature please?)